# Can't associate ubuntu.stackexchange with SO

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I can't associate [my account at ubuntu.stackexchange](https://askubuntu.com/users/1235/juha-syrjala) with [my account at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431/juha-syrjala) or other sites (meta, se, su etc.).

When I click *Associate with Stackoverflow* button I get this popup `user Id 1431 already associated with another account`.

Associating accounts have worked previously with SE sites when I started using a new site.

All of the accounts should be using the same OpenId account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your SO account is associated with all of your accounts except your Area 51 account, while your Ubuntu account is *only* associated with Area 51. Try disassociating your Ubuntu account before associating again.

Answer (score 0):

Set your email address on the Ubuntu SE account you get logged in with to the same email as your SO account, then send a message to the team (you can use the Contact Us link at the bottom of each site) and ask them to merge the 2 accounts on the Ubuntu site.